# access 2013 store course and grade for course

Tags: database, ms-access

i have a student table and a transcript table.

the transcript table will list all the courses a student has taken and the grades he/she recieved for those courses.

im not exactly sure how to store this in a way that makes sense.

this is what im trying to accomplish

Table: Transcript
field: id(PK)
field: studentID(FK)
field: coursesTaken - not sure how to enter multiple courses and multiple grades into a single field.

Answer (score 0):

Assume these two tables:

```
Students Table

Courses Table
```

Then you use a 'junction table':

```
StudentsCourses Table:
ID
StudentID, 
CourseID, 
Grade
...other stuff
```

It supplies the many-to-many relationship between students and courses.

Answer (score 0):

Your Students table will have a unique ID field (say, "StudentID"), as well as the Student Name, Address, Phone, whatever you want.

Your Courses table will have a unique ID (say, "CourseID"), as well as the Course Name, Description, Weight, Teacher, and whatever info you want.

You will have a 3rd table called StudentCourses (I guess this is what you call Transcripts).  This table will have **no** unique IDs.  Instead, it will just save the StudentID from the Students table, the CourseID from the Courses table, and the Grade.  You might also consider putting an AcademicYear or AcademicSemester field (or something like that), on the off chance a student needs to take the same course twice.

In your Relationships, put a one-to-many join from Students to StudentCourses on StudentID, another one-to-many join from Courses to StudentCourses on CourseID.  Boom.  All your data will now be accessible via a query.